# How to integrate TestRail with Java+Selenium+Eclipse+TestNG?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testrail

I'm doing automated tests with Java+Selenium+Eclipse+TestNG and I need to integrate the results with TestRail but I don't know how to do it...

I found the Java's Api (*http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/bindings-java*) and a lot of questions but any of the answers is useful. I only need the code to call the API and the path to put the Java's API.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to deal with api using TestRail, what is the selenium role here?

Comment: Because I'm testing with: Eclipse (framework), Java (language), TestNG (for detailed reports) and Selenium (I'm working with Chromedriver). My problem is the integration of TestRail's Api with Eclipse (and Java). I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Hi @Javier, Your question is too broad? what do u mean integration with eclipse? Do u mean how to run it?

Comment: Hi, yes... I don't understand how to integrate TestRail's Api into Eclipse (the objective is send the reports to TestRail). Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add test cases to an existing test run with the API from Java to TestRail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819170/how-to-add-test-cases-to-an-existing-test-run-with-the-api-from-java-to-testrail)

Answer (score 2):

You can check-out [Agiletestware Pangolin](https://www.agiletestware.com/pangolin) which can parse TestNG reports and upload results into TestRail from some CI system (e.g. Jenkins).
It also has Java annotation package which provides a set of Java annotations to integrate with TestRail (https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/pangolin-docs/en/latest/testing-tools/selenium-webdriver/).

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of Agiletestware Pangolin